# Value of an iterated integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Show that
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \frac{u_{\phi \phi}}{\sin\theta}  d\theta\,d\phi = 0
$$
Where $u$ is a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

I am unable to show that this integral is in fact $0$. This is because the of the $\frac{1}{\sin\phi}$, which ultimately yields undefined values over that interval for $\phi$.

Is it possible to show that this integral is undefined or is it really $0$?

Comment: Hint: replace the inner integral with two integrals,  one from $t$ to whatever and the other from whatever to $\r$ and then take limits of your variables

Comment: Is it really $u_{\phi\phi}$ in the numerator ?

Comment: $$\int_0^{2\pi }u_{\phi \phi}\,d\phi =u_{\phi}(\theta,2\pi)-u_{\phi}(\theta,0)=0$$assuming that $u_{\phi}$ is single-valued.